# converting ER model to relational model

Tags: database, model, relational-database, entity-relationship

I have problem with converting weak entity D in the picture below

[image]

should I do this `D(A_pri_key, B_pri_key)`

or should I separate `D1(A_pri_key) and D2(B_pri_key)` ?

I prefer the second choice better because the first one really looked like C when converting `C(A_pri_key, B_pri_key)`

Comment: If (1,1) means what I think it means then D _IS_ C.

Answer (score 5):

I think it should be the first choice.

When we construct the table for a weak entity, it has columns for each of its attributes and one extra column for putting in the Primary key of the Strong Entity Set(the entity set on which the weak entity depends).

**Approach 1**

In this case, there are 2 strong entities on which D depends. Thus primary key of D = Foreign key(pointing to Primary key of A) + Foreign key(pointing to Primary key of B). This would define a unique key for each instance of D.

**Approach 2**

Creating separate tables D1 and D2 will lead to redundancy.

In this case,

Primary key of D1 = Discriminator + Foreign key(pointing to A)

Primary key of D2 = Discriminator + Foreign key(pointing to B)

Here for a specific instance of D, we would end up having 2 primary keys, one from D1 and other from D2.